# How to change color of screen before the first render in react native?

Tags: react-native

First thing that I render in my App is black screen. Before it is loaded, and after launch screen is shown, some white screen appears for a while.

*I have set scheme to 'release'.

I don't see this issue in other react native apps. Ie. in Ads manager this screen is grey with some spinner.

Comment: You should be able to disable the message completely when your app is configured for release.

Comment: Thanks for answering ;) but message is not the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the question was changed.